# PostgreSQL select query (GPS)

Tags: php, postgresql, gps

**The problem!**

I have a PostgreSQL database on which I am saving GPS data of cars. Now I'm preparing history report and I have to show two different stutus to each car according to their speed, firs **stoped** if car speed remains 0 within 5 minutes, if more than 5 minutes then I have to show **parking**. I get data from GPS on each 10 seconds. Is there any way to do that? any help is appreciated.

**Here is the table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE gps_data_abl_soft
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gps_data_id_seq'::regclass),
  device_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT (-1),
  keyword character varying(30),
  coordinate geometry,
  date_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  message character varying(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  speed real NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
  angle real NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
  CONSTRAINT gps_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

[Here is the sample data from my table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZ5L.png)

Comment: In the sample data which i provided there is no cars with speed 0. And data is not recieved on each 10 seconds. Sorry for this :)

Comment: Are you wanting a solution in PHP, or in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If possible in PostgreSQL @ImClarky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tackled this problem myself by creating PostgreSQL function!

```
-- Function: stop_func(bigint)

-- DROP FUNCTION stop_func(bigint);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stop_func(IN device_id_param bigint)
  RETURNS TABLE(coordinate geometry, difference interval) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r record;
    stop_records stop_record[];
    speed_zero boolean;
    prev_date_time timestamp;
    coordinate geometry;
BEGIN

    speed_zero:=false;

    for r in SELECT g.coordinate, g.date_time, g.speed FROM gps_data_abl_soft g WHERE g.device_id=device_id_param  ORDER BY g.date_time
    LOOP
        IF r.speed=0 THEN
            IF NOT speed_zero THEN prev_date_time:=r.date_time; coordinate=r.coordinate; END IF;

            speed_zero:=true;
        ELSE 
            IF speed_zero THEN

                stop_records=array_append(stop_records,(coordinate, r.date_time-prev_date_time)::stop_record);
            END IF;

            speed_zero:=false;

        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM unnest(stop_records);



END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION stop_func(bigint)
  OWNER TO dr;
```

**Usage of this function**

```
 SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(ST_Multi(ST_Union(coordinate)), 4326)) AS coordinate,  
 difference from stop_func(device_id, start_time, end_time) group by difference;
```

**Sample result is here:**

[image]